# SOLR - Result grouping with Math on two fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a requirement in which I have a json structure like this:

```json
{
  "name":"xyz",
  "parent_id":123,
  "event_date":"1972-05-20T17:33:18.772Z"
}

{
  "name":"abc",
 "parent_id":123,
  "event_date":"1973-05-20T17:33:18.772Z"
}
```

I want the count of unique parent ids if the difference between the event dates is within X years(/months/days ) . Given this example , given a gap of 1 year the count will be 1

Answer (score 0):

Look into Streaming Aggregations if you're running Solr 6.x.  You'd probably

1. Create two separate query streams ("bornEvents", and "marriedEvents")
2. Merge them on "name".
3. Reduce them using (married-born: "ageAtMarriage")
4. Filter out records where "ageAtMarriage" > ...

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions

http://joelsolr.blogspot.com/2015/04/solrjio-computing-complement-of-two.html?m=1

Comment: Hello , In the third step , do you mean married date minus birthdate ?

Comment: Yes.  Because you want to filter on the difference between marriage and DOB, right?